# Convert a IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1> to List<string>

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-objects

I want a `List<string>` containing all the 'selected' series codes from this DataGridView:

[image]

I can get them as DataGridViewRow's, eg:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> selectedSeriesCodes =
                gridSeriesList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(g =>
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn1].Value.ToString()) &&
                    Convert.ToBoolean(g.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn1].Value) == true).ToList();
```

But I am aiming to get them as a `List<string>` purely for separation of concerns as I dont want to pass controls into business logic to ease testing, and just a fyi this is a excel vsto add-in.

I thought using LINQ with an anon type would do the trick, but it wont compile, eg:

```
List<string> selectedSeriesCodes = from x in gridSeriesList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                       where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn1].Value.ToString()) &&
                                        Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn1].Value) == true)
                                       select new { SeriesCode = x.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn2].ToString() };
```

> Error 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<AnonymousType#1>`' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`<string>`'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am sure this is possible, otherwise I'll just use a for loop.

Comment: You don't need to select a new anonymous type. Simply `select value.ToString();` and to remove the need to convert the result to a List<T> specifically, have the business code require an IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `.ToList()` :

```
List<string> selectedSeriesCodes = 
(from x in gridSeriesList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn1].Value.ToString() 
      &&  Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn1].Value) == true)
select x.Cells[ListDataSource.gridColumn2].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: +1, instead of DataGridViewTextBoxCell being returned I put in .Value to get string's as per  @NickBedford 's tip. Thanks guys.